# Send email fails using phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am unable to send an email in PHP using `PHPMailer` and don't know what part of my code is wrong. My code is below:

```
<?php
$msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  require 'vendor/autoload.php';

  function sendemail($to, $from, $fromName, $body) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    $mail->setFrom($from, $fromName);
    $mail->addAddress($to);
    $mail->Subject = 'Feedback';
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->isHTML(false);

    return $mail->send();
  }

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $body = $_POST['body'];

  if (sendemail('draysondw@gmail.com', $email, $name, $body)) {
    $msg = 'Email sent!';
  }
  else {
    $msg = 'Email Failed!';
  }
}  ?>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Feedback Form</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="index.php">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" required><br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" required><br>
    Message: <textarea name="body"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Feedback">
  </form>
  <br>
  <?php echo $msg; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Could you please help me to figure out what I am doing wrong to fix the email sending?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this:

```
$mail->setFrom($from, $fromName);
```

That's forgery and will either result in send failure, rejections or spam filtering of your messages. Do this instead:

```
$mail->setFrom($to);
$mail->addReplyTo($from, $fromName);
```

That way you're not forging the from address, but replies will still go to the submitter.

I also recommend reading [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) which deals with exactly this issue and many others.

Comment: It still does't work =(

Comment: You've not said what you mean exactly by "Doesn't work". Given you're sending via `mail()`, you need to check your mail server logs, as the guide suggests.